# PHP Remove the whitespaces from a PNG Image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I was trying to crop a png image, my problem is, I need to auto crop the whitespaces around my png image but I need to keep the transparency of the image too.

the below is my code what I tried

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("mypng.png"); 
$cropped = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_TRANSPARENT);  
// Convert it to a png file 
header('Content-type: image/png');   
imagepng($cropped);
```

The program is cropping the image successfully but it removes the transparency of the png image. instead it's adding a black color to the transparent area.

I tried couple of workarounds from Internet but no luck, somebody know what's happening here ?

Comment: `imagecropauto()`, "The program is cropping the image successfully", what program is this?  Or where is the code for these functions?

Comment: prob need to call [imagealphablending](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending) or [imagesavealpha](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) before imagepng not sure its been a while since using gd

Comment: @HoldOffHunger  The function is from the php GD library.

Answer (score -1):

well am not all that good with javascripts but you can use css like make the backgroun transparent hope it works.

```
   .imageclass img{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05) ;
 border-radius: 50%;
 }
```